# "Invalid value used as map key" when using React JSS's withStyles in a Storybook story

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I usually make styled React components using `react-jss`, which means I export them after wrapping them in the `withStyles` HOC.

Recently, I've decided to learn how to use Storybook hoping I could develop and test my components in isolation. However, if I set up a Storybook story around one of my styled components, I get an error in Storybook saying "Invalid value used as weak map key". If I "de-style" my component by commenting the `withStyles` HOC, everything works as expected.

To illustrate the issue, I set up [a repository on Github](https://github.com/savissimo/jss-storybook-bug). It is a new CRA React app with Typescript, Storybook and React JSS, consisting of two components, one of which is styled, and an empty story for each.

Is it possible to use Storybook in conjunction with React JSS? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Hey Simone, Thank you for raising this issue. Is this issue fixed for you ?

Comment: I haven't worked on it in the last few months, but no, I couldn't find any way to fix the issue.